# Custom adapter for GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, onclick

I'm getting data from DB and displayed in a `GridView` fine. But I need to put a separate button below each text displayed. When I click the button, I have to do some stuff. Here I used a custom list adapter for retrieved data from DB. How could I do that?

My code:

```
public class HomePage extends Activity  {
    private ArrayList<SingleElementDetails> allElementDetails=new ArrayList<SingleElementDetails>();
    DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
    String category, description;
    String data;
    String data1;
    GridView gridview;
    Button  menu;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

        menu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.menus);

        menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                gridview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                allElementDetails.clear();
                db.open();
                long id;
                //id=db1.insertTitle1(category, description,r_photo);
                Cursor cursor = db.getAllTitles1();
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    SingleElementDetails single=new SingleElementDetails();
                    single.setCateogry(cursor.getString(1));
                    single.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
                    single.setImage(cursor.getBlob(3));
                    allElementDetails.add(single);
                }
                db.close();
                CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(HomePage.this,allElementDetails);
                gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My customListAdapter:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private  ArrayList<SingleElementDetails> allElementDetails;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleElementDetails> results) {
        allElementDetails = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return allElementDetails.size();        
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return allElementDetails.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview1, null);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_entry);
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description_entry);
        textview.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).getCategory());
        textview1.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).getDescription());

        byte[] byteimage=allElementDetails.get(position).getImage();
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteimage);
        BitmapFactory.Options op=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        op.inSampleSize=12;
        Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream,null,op);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please would you mind to add the xml file of `R.layout.listview1`, so I can understand your example, I have a similar case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using CustomListAdapter, you will have to create your own adapter that extends BaseAdapter, create a layout for each grid item (extend LinearLayout) in this class have your textview then a button.

Nice Tut:

[Custom GridView](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..I've update my question with my CustomListAdapter code..that extends BaseAdapter too..Here where can i add those buttons?

Comment: The tutorial in a link is very outdated - for those who hasnt noticed its 2011 answer like me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleAdapter for GridView. This is the best way to design view of each item.

For example,
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listing-images-in-gridview-using-simple-adapter-in-android/