# Passing edittext values to gridview

Tags: android

Can we pass edittext values to gridview? If so, can you explain with example?

I checked and not able find anywhere in this site. I am new to android and java. so pls help me

Comment: Your question is not clear, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> listitems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
  
gridview1.setAdapter(listitems);
  
  
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0)
   {
    String input = edittext1.getText().toString();
          if(null!=input&&input.length()>0){ 
           
           list.add(input);
           listitems.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }
   }
   });
  
 }

Comment: you are setting the adapter earlier, without adding anything to the list. And you are adding items in list on button click, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a GrisView Adapter [custom adapter for gridview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324689/custom-adapter-for-gridview-in-android) , in it you can have a parameter lets say editTextValue . In its constructor you will initialize this .In the activity with edit text you will have

```
       String value = editText.getText();
       MyCustomGridViewAdapter  gridView = new MyCustomGridViewAdapter   (param1 , param2....., value);
```