# Add Device button defined, need to add new device on screen every time user clicks it

Tags: android

Screenshot of the App

[image]
I have a DeviceLayout.xml file which has a list of buttons in a grid as shown below. I used to pull it using an include tag in the MainLayout.

No activity is defined for DeviceLayout. Just xml file.

Now, the devices in the image are statically added. I want to make the button creation dynamic. If user clicks the "Add Device" Button, a new popup has to come up asking the details of the Device and it should be displayed on the home.

Please help. No idea how to do this.

Comment: So, `MainLayout.xml` is the layout of your MainActivity, and `DeviceLayout.xml` is a part of it. is that right?

Comment: You can use gridview and adapter. This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324689/custom-adapter-for-gridview-in-android.

Comment: Quang, Yes. I just pulled DeviceLayout into MainLayout.xml using include tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your activity you should use an adapter to populate the gridview.
Then, make your activity pass the dataset to be displayed to the gridview dynamically.
After adding a new device in your dataset, just update the grid ( you can use a adapter's notifydatasetchanged method).